# how to pass credentials https url using Python

Tags: python, url, https

i want to download files from remote server 
I have https link, how to pass the credentials?

```
url = 'https://test.com/download/'
f =urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = f.read()
print data
```

when i run this code, i am not getting any error from interpreter, the script ends waiting for few seconds. i get the html body of browser which was expecting the credentials

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but take a look at the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package. The first example involves an `https` request.

Comment: can i import requests module in 2.7 python, if so how?   Thanks :)

Comment: Check the [installation page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/) in their website

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you call wget linux command in python script. It supports passing credentials. You can use subprocess module in python  to execute wget cmd.